# Invalid urls show up as blank pages in my site

Tags: c#, iis-8

When a user enters an invalid URL, my site displays blank page.  I expect, it would go to my error page or display a 404 message.  I just took over this site and I've never seen this happen before.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Input:

```
User navigates to "<mysite>\invalid.aspx"
```

Expected:

```
404 error
```

Actual:

```
"<mysite>\invalid.aspx" appears to be a valid page with no content.
```

Comment: What does the `web.config` look like? In particular the `system.web` section(please verify there isn't any sensitive data in it like usernames/passwords before posting)?

Comment: Check which module handles such requests first, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: Have you enabled the custom error setting in your web.config or you have handled the error in the global.asax file or else? You should check the codes or the config file to make sure there is no special setting in it.